# Using windows CopyFile function to copy all files with certain name format

Tags: c++, windows, file-copying

Hello! I am updating some C code that copys files with a certain name. basically, I have a directory with a bunch of files named like so:

AAAAA.1.XYZ
AAAAA.2.ZYX
AAAAA.3.YZX
BBBBB.1.XYZ
BBBBB.2.ZYX

Now, In the old code, they just used a call to ShellExecute and used xcopy.exe. to get all the files starting with AAAAA, they just gave xcopy the name of the file as AAAAA.* and it knew to copy all of the files starting with AAAAA. now, im trying to get it to copy with out having to use the command line, and I am running into trouble. I was hoping CopyFile would be smart enough to handle AAAAA.* as the file to be copied, but it doesnt at all do what xcopy did. So, any Ideas on how to do this without the external call to xcopy.exe?

Comment: Here's some sample code to use regular expression masks with boost::filesystem, which would give you some platform independence (if that route were interesting to you): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257721/can-i-use-a-mask-to-iterate-files-in-a-directory-with-boost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `SHFileOperation` or `IFileOperation` (the latter being only available from Vista upwards but is now the recommended way according to MSDN). SHFileOperation supports wildcards and displays a progress by default, but there's also a flag for silent operation.

Check out the following MSDN links for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164(v=VS.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775771(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: To clarify: `SHFileOperation` is supported since the stone age; only `IFileOperation` is Vista upwards.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I guess my post was unclear in this regard. I edited it.

Comment: Just did this today. Ended up doing exactly what I wanted it to.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

Check this out as a starting point

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(VS.85).aspx

or even better this full example

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You would basically have to write code to reproduce the functionality in xcopy.  To do so, you must build a list of files by accessing the path and recursing through it.  Test each found entry with your pattern and keep only those that match.  Then iterate over that list with CopyFile.

See the following set of functions that can help you build the file list:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirent.h

It might just be easier to keep using xcopy unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: Just talked to the boss... although unable to tell me why this needs to be done, he insured me that it will be much better in the end.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do it.  I'd probably use a loop of FindFirstFile() / FindNextFile().

However, is there any reason you can't still use xcopy?  You can launch it with CreateProcess().  It isn't pretty, but it works.